# Как отфильтровать паразитные запуски метода по частоте их следования

Tags: java

Лисенер должен запустить метод `void go(int param)`, но если частота следования запусков менее секунды, то это должно считаться паразитным событием. И метод `go` не должен быть запущен.

Т.е. нужно реализовать метод `void noiseFilter(int param)`, который бы запускал `go(param)` в случае, если частота генерации событий лисенера менее 1 Герца (не чаще 1 раза в секунду).

Помогите новичку.

P.S. Привязка ко времени не супер критична, так как 1Гц это огромный threshold, который перекрывает паразитную частоту в десятки раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статьи про таймер поищи, как вариант.
Сам я таймер не использовал - но на мой взгляд решить можно так:
Создать в классе флаг, реализовать функцию Drop, которая этот флаг меняет на false.
Далее - когда запускается функция, она проверяет флаг, если он false - то можно работать, если true - то выполнение завершается.
Если функция может работать, она ставит этот флаг в true и запускает TimerTask, который обнулит этот флаг через секунду с помощью метода Drop.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/136878/ - статья про игровые циклы, думаю то, что надо.